# Indexes in join with filter

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle11g, left-join

Suppose the following SQL pseudocode:

```
select ... from A join B
on A.serial=27 and B.serial=34 and A.id=B.id;
```

Given that the tables are big, I need to use indexes for both `serial`, and obviously for the join condition `A.id=B.id`. Ideally, I need the filters applied before the join, as the result of the filters give much less rows than filter one table, then join, then filter second.

My question is: which combination of indexes would be fine for this situation? maybe two composites on A and B in the form `(serial id)`?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Your query is false. You are going to get all A rows.

Comment: I do want all A rows!

Comment: "need the filters applied before the join, as the result of the filters give much less rows than filter one table, then join, then filter second." - You are not filtering A, Only B

Comment: Bufffff what a mistake xD edited the original question

Comment: Assuming `serial` is a good filter on both sides, you got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Oracle, Not MySQL.
You don't need indexes for the `id` columns for join purposes, however -
it is a good idea to define ID columns as primary keys and this implicitly creates unique indexes

You do need indexes on the `serial` columns

```
Create index A_IX_SERIAL on A (SERIAL);
Create index B_IX_SERIAL on B (SERIAL);
```

P.s.
How much is "much less rows"?
As much rows are return, it becomes a less good idea to use index.

Comment: Sorry, but why isn't necessary to index the joined columns?

Comment: @Alex, because Oracle unlike MySQL supports hash join.

Comment: Very interesting...does hash join support multiple joined columns?

Comment: @Alex, Yes, it support multiple columns. Hash join main features (1)  equality predicates only (2) memory bound.

Comment: I'll try it on monday...after the filters, A has 2k rows, but B has 3M!

Comment: @Alex, so it would be most likely not a good idea to index B. If B is big (as in, much more than 3M records) consider defining partitions.

Comment: Not an option in my enterprise :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129117/discussion-between-alex-and-dudu-markovitz).